# SharePoint 2007/2010

Tags: sharepoint

I'm a developer with 5 years of MCMS development and without a single know how with SharePoint.
I want to use the CMS capabilities of Sharepoint to migrate my applications but I DONT KNOW HOW TO START!!!!!!

In my actual projects i have a Visual Studio solution with all my code, my templates and my usercontrols...

I cannot see how can i do the same thing with Sharepoint :(
I want to customise my site like i did before, i want to create pages based on templates like i did before.

Anyone knows where i can find a walkthrough that explains me that?

Thank U All.

Comment: My first job a long time ago was on a project that had to do this.  I think we converted the usercontrols into things called "webparts".  Sorry thats all I can offer :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you are going to have to learn SharePoint. Even the WCM features are a big topic, and probably the best book is Andrew Connell's "SharePoint 2007 Web Content Management Development" - I don't think a 2010 version is available yet. The good news is that I think the MCMS product had a big influence on how the SharePoint WCM features were architected, so the underlying principles will be similar.

SharePoint 2010 has a Visual Web Part that will encapsulate a user control which might make the transition easier. Also see my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096879/how-would-you-convert-an-asp-net-site-to-work-as-a-sharepoint-site/1114545#1114545) about converting an ASP.NET site to SharePoint which might have some relevant information.

Most of the information about converting from MCMS to SharePoint is for the 2007 version of the product. This two-part [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466172(v=office.12).aspx) seems to be the best starting point.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot see how can i do the same thing with Sharepoint :( I want to customise my site like i did before, i want to create pages based on templates like i did before.

Problem is, SharePoint is **not** MCMS, no matter how Microsoft tries to brand it as its successor.

Creating sites in SharePoint is almost opposite of how things we were done in MCMS were you build from the ground up using ASPX templates, user controls and placeholders. In SharePoint, you'll have to strip out most of the OOB stuff you don't need. The recommended approach to custom development is through web parts, CAML, and the SharePoint APIs.